# Cannot debug Qt Android Project

Tags: android, qt, debugging

I have a Qt application which I am compiling both on windows and android.(using Qt Creator 4.6.0 with Qt 5.10.1 , Android SDK27)

The problem is that debug output is not getting printed on console for Android build. That is same for on emulator or real device. No qDebug outputs. But i can see some Java outputs on console. As I can understand the editor can connect to debug server:

```
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=53KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=53KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I zygote  : Do full code cache collection, code=121KB, data=90KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=106KB, data=66KB
W linker  : "/data/app/org.mikrodev.vpclient-WMiXF2CO37aeO1BnWi5xGg==/lib/x86/libViewPLUSClient.so" unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x116483
D         : (null):0 ((null)): QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: extra parameters: Bundle[{debug_ping=true, gdbserver_socket=/data/data/org.mikrodev.vpclient/debug-socket, qml_debug=true, gdbserver_command=/data/data/org.mikrodev.vpclient/lib/libgdbserver.so --multi +/data/data/org.mikrodev.vpclient/debug-socket, qmljsdebugger=port:6680,block,services:DebugMessages,QmlDebugger,V8Debugger,QmlInspector, ping_socket=org.mikrodev.vpclient.ping_pong_socket}]
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: removing gdb socket /data/data/org.mikrodev.vpclient/debug-socket
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: starting /data/user/0/org.mikrodev.vpclient/lib/libgdbserver.so --multi +/data/data/org.mikrodev.vpclient/debug-socket
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: gdbserver started
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: waiting for socket at /data/data/org.mikrodev.vpclient/debug-socket, attempt 0
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: socket ok
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Debug socket accepted
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Incoming socket OK
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: Got pid acknowledgment
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: ping not requested
I Qt JAVA : DEBUGGER: pong not requested
D OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D gralloc_ranchu: Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected. Loading gralloc.default.so from /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so...
W linker  : "/data/data/org.mikrodev.vpclient/qt-reserved-files/plugins/styles/libqandroidstyle.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=120KB, data=81KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=120KB, data=81KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

I can see some QML and Android specific debug output like:

```
I zygote  : NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 52(47KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 60% free, 990KB/2MB, paused 641us total 106.181ms
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(734)] "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.", source: file:///data/user/0/org.mikrodev.vpclient/files/ScadaProjects/untitled2/images/map_1526578461228.html (734)
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(734)] "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.", source: file:///data/user/0/org.mikrodev.vpclient/files/ScadaProjects/untitled2/images/map_1526578461228.html (734)
I chatty  : uid=10085(u0_a85) org.mikrodev.vpclient identical 2 lines
I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(734)] "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.", source: file:///data/user/0/org.mikrodev.vpclient/files/ScadaProjects/untitled2/images/map_1526578461228.html (734)
I zygote  : NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 47(62KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 60% free, 1023KB/2MB, paused 6.261ms total 87.462ms
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I chatty  : uid=10085(u0_a85) org.mikrodev.vpclient identical 17 lines
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I chatty  : uid=10085(u0_a85) org.mikrodev.vpclient identical 9 lines
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I chatty  : uid=10085(u0_a85) org.mikrodev.vpclient identical 3 lines
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=243KB, data=156KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=243KB, data=156KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I chatty  : uid=10085(u0_a85) org.mikrodev.vpclient identical 10 lines
W zygote  : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

But no qDebug() or qWarning() outputs are printed. How can i get qDebug() outputs?

Comment: Show a screen shot of your Android kit.

Comment: This is a known bug that was fixed in 4.6.1 - as far as I know it only happens with Android 8 devices. See https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/dist/changes-4.6.1.md?h=4.6